# Why when setting the form1.ShowInTaskBar to false it's throwing exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to start the form in some case in the tray icon.
So in the constructor I did:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    settingsFileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) +
        settingsFileDirectory;
    if (!Directory.Exists(settingsFileDirectory))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(settingsFileDirectory);
    }
    settingsFile = Path.Combine(settingsFileDirectory,settingsFile);
    if (!File.Exists(settingsFile))
    {
        File.Create(settingsFile);
    }

    string[] values = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(settingsFile).Split(',');
    downloadonstart = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[0]));
    loadonstart = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[1]));
    startminimized = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[2]));
    displaynotifications = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[3]));

    lvnf = new ListViewNF();
    lvnf.Location = new Point(250, 18);
    lvnf.Size = new Size(474, 168);
    lvnf.View = View.Details;
    this.SuspendLayout();
    lvnf.LabelEdit = true;
    lvnf.Columns.Add("From", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lvnf.Columns.Add("Subject", 200);
    lvnf.Columns.Add("Date", 300);
    lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
    lvnf.ColumnClick += lvnf_ColumnClick;
    lvnf.Click += lvnf_Click;
    this.Controls.Add(lvnf);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
    label8.Visible = false;
    pbt.Size = new Size(216, 10);
    pbt.Location = new Point(8, 330);
    pbt1.Size = new Size(396, 10);
    pbt1.Location = new Point(250, 198);
    this.Controls.Add(pbt1);
    groupBox1.Controls.Add(pbt);
    pbt.Text = "0%";
    pbt1.Text = "0%";
    //LoadFullMessages();
    if (startminimized == true)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
    if (loadonstart == true)
    {
        backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    if (downloadonstart == true)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Then inside the `Form1_Resize` event I did this:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        this.Hide();
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
}
```

What makes the exception is the line:

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Then I click on break and I see this:

[image: Exception]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would guess that a side-effect of calling `this.ShowInTaskbar = false;` is causing the form to be resized. Hence the recursion.

Comment: Moved the minimized setting to the form1 Load event solved it.  Moved this part to the Load event: if (startminimized == true)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            }

Comment: That seems a good solution.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on providing quality samples in the posts. 99% of code in the post is not related to the problem. Also make sure to post exception information as text, not as an image.

Comment: @MatthewWatson why did you remove your answer? Looks reasonable to me.

Comment: The snippet is not good enough to provide a repro.  But yes, ShowInTaskbar is a "difficult" property.  It requires the native window to be re-created, that can have unpleasant side-effects if it happens at the wrong time.  You just don't need it at all, if you Hide() the window then the taskbar button is already removed anyway.